# PowerDNS does not resolve TXT records

Tags: domain-name-system, dig, dns-server, powerdns, txt-record

My PowerDNS DNS server 3.3 does not resolve TXT records.

Database looks like this:

[PowerDNS database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYhkQ.jpg)

When I try to dig my server for TXT entry they are not being shown:

```
[root@nowosci powerdns]# dig @ns1.nowosci.org private._domainkey.nowosci.org TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13208.13-P2-RedHat-9.9.3-4.P2.el6 <<>> @ns1.nowosci.org private._domainkey.nowosci.org TXT
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 58314
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 2800
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;private._domainkey.nowosci.org.        IN      TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
nowosci.org.            1800    IN      SOA     ns1.nowosci.org. admin.adminonline.gr. 2013092526 3600 1800 604800 1800

;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 62.21.44.49#53(62.21.44.49)
;; WHEN: śro wrz 25 13:36:45 CEST 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 119
```

and

```
[root@nowosci powerdns]# dig @ns1.nowosci.org nowosci.org TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13208.13-P2-RedHat-9.9.3-4.P2.el6 <<>> @ns1.nowosci.org nowosci.org TXT
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 3920
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 2800
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nowosci.org.                   IN      TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
nowosci.org.            1800    IN      SOA     ns1.nowosci.org. admin.adminonline.gr. 2013092526 3600 1800 604800 1800

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 62.21.44.49#53(62.21.44.49)
;; WHEN: śro wrz 25 13:37:31 CEST 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Delete the dot at the end of TXT records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There cannot be dots at the end of domain name:

Instead of this:

```
_domainkey.nowosci.org.
private._domainkey.nowosci.org.
```

Should be this:

```
_domainkey.nowosci.org
private._domainkey.nowosci.org
```